# Jquery datepicker is not working on this case

Tags: jquery

I am using icontrigger date picker in my application. By doing this onSelect function is not working.

```
$(function() 
{
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.gif"
    onSelect: function(date) 
    {
        //alert(date);
        window.location="emerTnDetailsMgmt.do?method=populateTlfEmerTNDate&regDate="+date;
     } 
     });
 });

<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="<%=formatprev%>">
```

Any suggetion..

Comment: Next time you post a question, find out what error message code gives. You should have seen that it gave a syntaxerror, and thus be able to fix it before asking a question. You can find error messages by opening the developer console in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing comma after `buttonImage` attribute....

```
buttonImage: "images/cal.gif"
-----------------------------^
```

Try below,

```
  $(function() 
    {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
        onSelect: function(date) 
        {
            //alert(date);
            window.location="emerTnDetailsMgmt.do?method=populateTlfEmerTNDate&regDate="+date;
         } 
         });
    });
```